# How do I pass a while loop index to append to file name to operate on?

Tags: python, indexing, while-loop, arguments

I need to operate on list of files in dir. Using a while loop to loop through all files and need to append to file name "i". <file suffix>. How do I do this in Python3.x?

I put the code in while loop and tried to append but it did not work..

```py
while x in range(101):
    print(x)
    file = x.file
    print(file)
    # code block to execute on each file
    else:
        print("all files processed")
```

Comment: It would be include more details, including your output. Please check if [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3207973/2081835) helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the string formatting operator to append the index to the file name:

```
while x in range(101):
    print(x)
    file = '{}.file'.format(x)
    print(file)
    # code block to execute on each file
    else:
        print("all files processed")
```